# Why is there a link to clone some gists in desktop and not others?

Tags: git, github, gist

On all GitHub repositories there is alink "Clone in Desktop". Very practial IMO.

On some, but not all gists, there is also such a "Cloine in Desktop". What is the difference? And can I still use GitHub for Windows to clone those gists without doing it from the command line?

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the interface/accounts work) or direct to GitHub:Support

Comment: Thanks @random. Just asked GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

At the time, in 2014, the button format just changed from

```
 https://gist.github.com/raw/3227047/clonegistinmac.user.j
```

to:

```
 https://gist.github.com/raw/3227047/clonegistindesktop.user.js
```

As illustrated by [those revisions](https://gist.github.com/abernier/3227047/revisions) to the [clonegistindesktop.user.js](https://gist.github.com/abernier/3227047): that userscript should work for all gist.